# How do we know that the Maclaurin Series can always be used to approximate a function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I'm aware of the formula that can be used to derive the Maclaurin series for a particular function:

[image: Maclaurin series formula]

My question is - how do we know that all functions can be represented as an infinite series of powers of x? Are there some functions for which a Maclaurin series cannot be derived?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: We actually know that *not* all functions can be represented with a Maclaurin series. Some functions are analytic, and if they are then their MacLaurin series has a radius of convergence. These two ideas help determine if and where a function can be represented with a MacLaurin series.

Answer (score 1):

Functions for which the Taylor series in a point gives the real values of the function are known as *[analytic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function)* or $C^{\omega}$. Not every analytic function is analytic over the whole real line: for instance,
$$ \log(1-x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n} $$
holds only if $x\in[-1,1)$.

Moreover, not every $C^{\infty}$ function is an analytic function: consider, for instance, that
$$ f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}0 &\text{if}& x=0,\\ e^{-1/x^2}&\text{if}&x\neq 0.\end{array}\right.$$
is a $C^{\infty}$ function and all the derivatives of $f$ in zero are zero, hence by assuming that $f$ is an analytic function in a neighbourhood of the origin one has $e^{-1/x^2}=0$ for some small $x$, leading to a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what an analytic function is.  What exactly do you mean by "all the derivatives of f in zero are zero"?

Comment: @BenGorman: that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$.